# data-* attributes being set to undefined when using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, methods, attr

When I try and access some custom data-* attributes using jquery, the variables are set to undefined.

I set a bunch of different variables to other html attributes, and all the ones without the data-* prefix are set properly (ex. id = the html id). My question is: why are the data-* html attributes being set to undefined and the built in ones aren't?

This is a private project so I can't show much code, but I will change the variable names and show a snippet

```
 var $elm = $(this);
 var thisID = $elm.attr('id')
 var windowOpen = $elm.attr('data-window-open')
 var className = $elm.attr('class')
 var dataName = $elm.attr('data-name')
 var title = $elm.attr('title')
```

I should also mention "this" refers to an html 'a' element.

I'm hoping to retrieve the html attribute values from the data-* attributes.

EDIT: Here's the html element that "this" is referring to:

```
<a class="related-widget-wrapper-link add-related input-group-addon" id=" add_id_{{ name }}" data-window-open="true" data-href-template="{{ add_related_url }}?{{ url_params }}" data-name="addAnotherWindow" title="{% blocktrans %}Add another {{ model }}{% endblocktrans %}">
  </a>
```

Comment: use `.data("name")`

Comment: I tried this but it still returns undefined. Any other suggestions?

Comment: can you include the HTML part where is the element that `this` refers to ?

Comment: Added Calvin! Check out my edit!

Comment: and what is the function/method that is called that assing those variables? Because doing a test here, it worked for me, shown "addAnotherWindow"